# Inserting multiple entries into an SQL table via python lists using mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

```
mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE table_1(ID int, NAME varchar(25), SPORT varchar(15))")

id_list=[stuff]
name_list=[stuff]
sport_list=[stuff]

for i in id_list:
    mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES(id_list[i], name_list[i], sport_list[i])")
```

And here it shows this error:

```
ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[i], name_list[i], sport_list[i])' at line 1
```

Is there a better way to do this? Or am I forced to insert values one by one?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (id, name, sport) in zip(id_list, name_list, sport_list):
    query = "INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES(%s, '%s', '%s')" % (id, name, sport)
    mycursor.execute(query)
```

The problem with your code is that you are sending the strings id_list[i], name_list[i] ....etc and not the actual values of those.

Be careful with the single quotes, on '%s', you need those if what you are sending is a string.

In this example, please also check how you can iterate over multiple lists at the same time.

Comment: I didn't think of zip before. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping you could use `executemany`.

Here's a small example.

```py
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='username', password='password',
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='test')

cur = cnx.cursor()

#cur.execute("CREATE TABLE table_1(ID int, NAME varchar(25), SPORT varchar(15))")

id_list=[1,2,3]
name_list=['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']
sport_list=['Sport1', 'Sport2', 'Sport3']

data = zip(id_list, name_list, sport_list)

sql = "INSERT INTo table_1 VALUES(%s, %s, %s)"

cur.executemany(sql, data)

cnx.commit()
```

Comment: I initially wanted to use executemany  but didnt think of zip. Thanks!